DNS and routing under wsl
I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu on Windows and connect to a private network using the Twingate VPN. When I start my WSL2 instance, I want it to automatically configure the DNS server and routes from my Windows host if the VPN is connected. However, if the VPN is disconnected, I'd like it to fall back to the default DNS and routing configuration.
Does anyone know how to set up WSL2 so it dynamically adjusts its network configuration based on the VPN status each time it starts?
Any guidance on configuring WSL2 to handle this routing and DNS switch automatically would be much appreciated!
